# American vs British English and spelling edits

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently noticed someone applied a minor edit to one of my answers that changes a word from British English to American English. I searched around a bit, and found similar questions on other SE meta sites. The first relates to [asking questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3225/is-it-prefered-to-use-english-us-spelling-to-english-uk), and the second to [adding tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/whats-the-deal-with-retagging-from-uk-english-to-us-english). I am just curious if UX SE has a "preferred language" for consistency?

Comment: Revert! American English is obviously wrong.

Comment: Slippery slope.  Next they'll want to change the date to dd/mm/yyyy ;)

Comment: [For the avoidance of doubt, there is no such thing as 'American English'. There is the English language and there are mistakes.](https://twitter.com/Queen_UK/status/207376116447584256) - Elizabeth Windsor

Comment: Just like on Wikipedia, the post should stay in the English variant it was originally written in. Otherwise people are going to start writing bots to automatically change "color" to "colour", then counter-bots to do the opposite and we end up with a massive bot war on Stackexchange.

Comment: Use British English.  Americans can't spell, so they won't notice anyway. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official *version* of English, aside from [StackExchange being an English Language site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/).

It is possible that when questions / answers written in one country are edited by someone in another country their own browser spellchecker will highlight words as incorrectly spelt when infact they are just spelt according to the original posters language. Perhaps this is the situation here? (I don't know the actual post you are referring to to be able to confirm).

We wouldn't encourage editing posts just to change from US to UK (or vice-versa), and if a suggested edit came up for authorisation that only included such a change it should be rejected as 'Too Minor'.

Comment: I would prefer new version to show through without credit to "minor" editor.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us) that seems to draw a clear distinction between body text (doesn't matter) and tag text (only American English). That came from the accepted answer. The most-upvoted answer says "it should not matter, so do not edit". It is from SE Meta though.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the conclusion there (the UI text is American english, so the tags may as well match it) but body text doesn't need such consistency. I'd only add that you should reject edits that only add/remove Britishisms/etc from a post as Too Minor

Comment: Do you mean Americanisms? :P

Comment: **+1**: This answers the question about tag names.